# CSS3 bounce keyframes not working

Tags: wordpress, css, animation, bounce

I am currently trying to create a bounce animation for a down arrow. However I can get the animation to work but the keyframes are not being recognised, no matter how I change the values. The arrow is a font-awesome fa-chevron-down. My website is being built with wordpress.

My CSS code is:

```
.view-more > i{
    font-size: 39px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce{
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
    40% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
    60% {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
    40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
    60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
    40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
    60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-3px);
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong as I have Googled and from what I have found this should work.

I have also tried jsfiddle and the keyframes are working. So I'm really confused. https://jsfiddle.net/yewtree/qh3v7fdk/

Any help would appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: I have never seen keyframe syntax ordered like that before. Does duplicating them and putting them in order work? (As in: `0,20,40,50,60,80,100` instead of `0,20,50,80,100,40,60`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. However, I have changed the order of the `animation` property to include the vendor prefixes first (which is preferred):

```css
.view-more > i {
  font-size: 39px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
     -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
          animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce{
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-3px);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>  
  <div class="view-more">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what you problem is, see the snippet below. I have modified it a bit to make all the values follow each other (and in general make it more legible), and have also increased your meager values for a bit more buff ones, so we can see the difference. Your animation is working as expected.

```css
@keyframes bounce{
   0%    { transform: translateY(0); }
   20%   { transform: translateY(0); }
   40%   { transform: translateY(-50%); }
   50%   { transform: translateY(0); }
   60%   { transform: translateY(-20%); }
   80%   { transform: translateY(0); }
   100%  { transform: translateY(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
   0%    { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
   20%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
   40%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); }
   50%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
   60%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(-20%); }
   80%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
   100%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
   0%    { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
   20%   { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
   40%   { -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); }
   50%   { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
   60%   { -moz-transform: translateY(-20%); }
   80%   { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
   100%  { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
}
div {
  background:red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: 1000ms bounce infinite;
  animation: 1000ms bounce infinite;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```